# Installer created with Electron-Winstaller runs briefly then quit

Tags: electron

[image]

My installer window show up for a quarter of second then quits without installing

What can I do to find what causes this bug?

Answer (score 0):

Restart machine, clear cache, download installer again and try again.

Comment: I restarted my PC, cleared system cache and compiled my installer again, and I still face the same problem